# How do I pass a property value containing a semicolon on the MSBuild command line when running it from PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, msbuild

I'm attempting to pass a property to MSBuild. The property is a semicolon-delimited list of values. Unlike [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6051054/how-do-i-pass-a-property-to-msbuild-via-command-line-that-could-be-parsed-into-a), I'm running MSBuild from PowerShell.

I get:

```
PS> msbuild .\Foo.sln /p:PackageSources="\\server\NuGet;E:\NuGet"

MSBUILD : error MSB1006: Property is not valid.
Switch: E:\NuGet
```

If I run the same command from Command Prompt, it works fine. How do I get it to work in PowerShell?

Comment: Try using the backtick escape character ("`") in front of the semicolon.  Possibly other characters in that string, as well.

Comment: Backtick doesn't work -- the problem is that MSBuild expects /p:PropA=ValA;PropB=ValB. The semicolon needs 'escaping' from MSBuild, not from PowerShell. Adding the quotes should fix this, but PoSh pulls them out when passing the command line on.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Wrap the parameter in single quotes:

```
... '/p:PackageSources="\\Server\NuGet;E:\NuGet"'
```

On PowerShell v3 try this:

```
msbuild .\Foo.sln --% /p:PackageSources="\\Server\NuGet;E:\NuGet"
```

Comment: Can't check v3 (I uninstalled it when it broke my PowerShell console settings -- font, colours, size), but the extra single quotes work.

Answer (score 6):

Also using ASCIII value helps:

```
msbuild .\Foo.sln /p:PackageSources="\\Server\NuGet%3BE:\NuGet"
```

Comment: Hi, you are answering a pretty old question. Can you elaborate why your answer is better than the ones that were already provided?

Comment: Sure. In this case, you do not need to change the script, that's only difference. That was actually my problem - I was using distribution plugin that triggered the build. And since I was not allowed to touch the plugin's code, this solved it more suitably.

Comment: Cool! Next time I would add that text directly to your post (edit) where it can be easly found for a future reader. You can still do that (I'd recommend it).

Comment: In case anyone got here the same way I did... I had the same error for dotnet build -p:TreatWarningsAsErrors=true -p:NoWarn="CS0618;CS1705" however %3B (semicolon) did not work but %2C (comma) did.

Answer (score -2):

*VBScript* function below can be used to escape property values passed to *MSBuild.exe* inside double quotes:

```
    Function Escape(s)
      Escape = s

      Set objRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp") 

      objRegEx.Global = True 
      objRegEx.Pattern = "(\\+)?"""

      Escape = objRegEx.Replace(Escape,"$1$1\""") 

      objRegEx.Pattern = "(\\+)$"

      Escape = objRegEx.Replace(Escape,"$1$1") 
    End Function
```

The following example demonstrates usage of *Escape()* function

```
    Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")        
    objShell.Run "msbuild.exe echo.targets /p:Param1=""" & Escape("ParamValue1") & """,Param2=""" & Escape("ParamValue1") & """", 1, True
```

Comment: You should ask (and self-answer) a question where this answer can live. It's got nothing to do with PowerShell.