# Is "AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings"-option the only way to prevent connection string tokenization?

Tags: msbuild, msdeploy, webdeploy, msbuild-propertygroup

I am still trying to get my head around MSBuild things.
Currently I am fiddling around with deploying via powershell script using the generated scripts from the [PackageWeb-Nuget-Package](https://nuget.org/packages/PackageWeb) ([video demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-LvUJFI8CzM)). I have been trying that out for a few days now and it seemed to work. But "suddenly" the connection string in the generated web.config is tokenized and instead of the connection string in question I see

```
connectionString="$(ReplacableToken_DefaultConnection-Web.config Connection String_0)
```

I wrote "suddenly" because I could not link this (for me new) behaviour to anything I had done in the previous hours.

So to sum it up: The deployment from package is working fine, also the correct config transformation is being applied, but I end up with this tokenized connection string.

I realize that I can fix this if I insert

```
<AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings>false</AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings>
```

into a PropertyGroup (I just put it into the generated targets-file that the Nuget-Package creates)

However I really dislike this, having to insert this additional value into each project that might need it; especially because I did not know I need this adjustment in the first place. Yesterday it worked and I did not have this extra line inserted into any projects- or targets-file.

So I was hoping that maybe someone knows an extra switch, trick or setting that might have an additional influence on how that is working, too.

Comment: This is old, but would you plz share your findings on how you did it without specifying this loooooog property in .*proj file?

Comment: @Ostati To be honest, I did not "solve" that at any point - the property `AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings=false` is still part of my deployment process; though I have not run into any problems with that, besides esthetically, I would also still be very interested if this can be circumvented in any way.

Comment: @Ostati To add to that, the primary thing that I disliked about this was having to modify each project ('s proj-file) for that; however you do not have to do that, you can pass properties as parameters to `msbuild` - that way you override already existing properties in your proj-files or add new ones that you need (just like `AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings`) hope this helps you ;) (example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6052146/2186023)

Comment: @DrCopyPaste I am trying to use `AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings` and `DisableAllVSGeneratedMSDeployParameter` for publishing Web Deploy Packages from Visual Studio 2013.  Where exactly do you put these?  In the `csproj` file?  I've tried that and it gives an error.

Comment: @Heinrich I am actually calling msbuild directly and override properties with that cmd like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6052146/2186023); you should however also be able to [use those parameters in your project file directly](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465342%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). You need to watch out if those parameters are altered in a later stage, for example passed in command line will override (augment) properties known from the project file.

Comment: @DrCopyPaste It didn't work when I put it directly in the project file, it would create an error on build. I put it in the publish settings file `.pubxml` that is created in `Project Folder/Properties/PublishProfiles` when you create a profile in the Publish->Web Deploy Package dialog. There wasn't an error after putting it there.

Answer (score 7):

Microsoft is using auto parameterization by default. This includes het connectionstrings. You can disable this by adding this to the project file.

`<AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings>false</AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings>`

For disabling all transforms you can add this as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465342(v=vs.100).aspx).

`<TransformWebConfigEnabled>false</TransformWebConfigEnabled>`

For disable all the parameters for a deployment package:
`<DisableAllVSGeneratedMSDeployParameter>true</DisableAllVSGeneratedMSDeployParameter>`

Answer (score 1):

Now that my company has been using TFS's "Release Manager" tool, which works off of a single build, we don't use web.config transforms anymore and instead use MS WebDeploy's parameters.xml method for swapping out values for different environments. However, I ran into the issue of the 'auto-gen'd' conn string mentioned above. Below is one work around for it.

If you're using parameters.xml files in your project, if you give your parameter the same name as the auto-gen'd one for your connection string, it works.

So below I have a 'DBConnectionNameHere' (what would be my example connectionStrings 'name' in the web.config) and then I just append "-Web.config Connection String" to the name. Now instead of the auto-gen'd conn string overriding my own in the parameters.xml file it will work and just add an extra and harmless 'parameterEntry' child tag.

For example:

```
<parameter name="DbConnectionNameHere-Web.config Connection String" defaultValue="#{TokenHereOrActualValue}#">

  <parameterEntry kind="XmlFile" scope="\\web.config$" 
match="/configuration/connectionStrings/add[@name='DbConnectionNameHere']/@connectionString" />

</parameter>
```

Hope that helps someone!

Chris

Answer (score 0):

I've noted that things like $(ReplacableToken_ seem to happen randomly when publishing and was able to fix the situation by doing a cleanup before rebuilding and republishing.
However, since you cannot really know unless you always manually check the web.config after publishing, I've also added

```
<AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings>false</AutoParameterizationWebConfigConnectionStrings>
```

to the web service project in question.